# How to mitigate and ignore a constant rotation in computer vision (kalman filter, optical flow)

Tags: computer-vision, opencv3.0, kalman-filter, opticalflow

I have a camera attached to a "blade" that is rotating at a constant RPM in the y axis, the camera is facing out in the x plane looking along the blade. So with this in mind, is there a way to avoid the background motion and only look for objects that are passing across the field of view that are not the same background velocity/rotation.

Would it best to approach this using a dynamics approach, since I know the rotation I can create a rotation matrix and translate this within the same plane. But using that how would I implement this into an openCV code to look for the motion of an object. I was looking into Kalman filters and think that this may be the best approach especially using a linear dynamic model. I could implement this rotation as the noise matrix?

Edit. I have since added a better image of what I am trying to convey, I have a better understanding of Kalman filters. Let's say using a cascade detector, and a Kalman filter I am able to both track the centroids and the predicted position of the ball hitting/passing by this blade. How would I theoretically detect if the ball hit or not? Would a good way be to get the subtracted abs value of the detected ball center and the expected Kalman trajectory and if its greater than a threshold we know it deviated from its expected path and therefore its a hit? Or would there be a better way using position/time.

[image: This is the "blade" the rotation is occuring in the y axis and rotating, with respect to this the ground is going down and the blade is going up.]

Comment: It is quite hard to understand the setup you are describing. Consider adding a drawing with the axes labelled, or a picture of the physical setup.

Comment: Hello, I have tried to add a drawing that my better show what I am talking about.